# Open all files in a folder starting with a certain letter

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to open all excel files in a folder that start with a certain string. For example, let's say that I want all files that start with 'hello'. From the following list:
1)hello1.xls
2)hello2.xls
3)other2.xls
4)hello3.xls
5)other3.xls

I would like to open files 1, 2, 4. I would like to open each file, process it and then open then next file. So the workflow should something like:

```
  for i in files:
     if string=='hello'
       pd.read_xls(i)
       do things
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your effort. What did you try, what is your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all files are in your current working directory, you can use `glob` like this:

```
import glob
file_names = glob.glob("hello*")
for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            # do things
```